# Identity server 4 session/cookie questions

Tags: c#, session, cookies, identityserver4, openid-connect

I Have question related user's session.

I would like the user to be logged out after a period of inactivity (5 minutes). For that, on the client side, I configured the cookie like this

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.SlidingExpiration = false;
            })
```

After 5 minutes of inactivity I have a redirect which is done on my identiyserver but with a silent Re-Authentication. Argh.

Still on the client side, I tested by adding this property to the OIDC configuration level

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
   [...]
   options.Prompt = "login";
   [...]
});
```

After the 5 minutes I have an authentication request, but the SSO no longer works with this client.

In short, I have the impression of lacking competence or hindsight when it comes to this notion of session.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `max_age` parameter is probably what you want in this case. This will force interactive auth if the last time the authenticated is more than `max_age` seconds in the past.

Since this parameter can be tampered with you can then also verify in your client that the `auth_time` claim is within acceptable limits before re-establishing the session.

Note you will likely want to have sliding expiration turned on in your client since it will force them out after 5 minutes regarless of activity currently.

Comment: I tested by indicating a value for max_age (from a few minutes to a few days) but each time I have a return from Identity server which tells me

"Showing login: Requested MaxAge exceeded."

[edit]I found reason for error:

request.Subject.GetAuthenticationTime() = 2021/07/06.

Any idea where this value can come from and how to reset it?

Comment: It comes from the `auth_time` claim in the auth cookie which should be managed automatically by IDS4